# Group data in pivot tables by advanced rules

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I was wondering is there any way how to create pivot table in Excel with bit more advanced group by rules?
I am trying to create pivot table that will represent number of records for specified data ranges. 
less than 3 days, 3 - 7 days, more than 7 days

I am looking for something simple. I would prefer to do it using Pivot table. Data over which I am trying to create this pivot table are generated on daily basis and input table already contains about 14 different columns. Therefore adding any additional columns is not the way to go

These are imput data

[image: Input data]

This is, what I am able to achieve

[image]

And this is, what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Is there any way how to achieve something like this using pivot table? 
I am able to create something like this using macro, but it is kinda overkill. I assume there is something like this already implemented in Excel

Answer (score 0):

Add a column in your raw data (with a suitable formula - Band1, Band2, Band3 etc) and use that in COLUMNS for the PivotTable.

*Alternatively*

Add three Calculated fields

`=Aging<3`
`=AND(Aging>=3,Aging<=7)`
`=Aging>7`

and add the counts for those:

[image: SO28700290 example]

Comment: this is kinda overkill as well, my input data table has about 14 columns and data within this table are generated dynamically on daily basis and it takes some time. Adding extra logic within this table is not a good idea at all

Comment: my fault. i will fix it